# Get-Content | Measure-Object -Line to Variable

Tags: powershell

Let me preface this by saying I'm completely new to Powershell and I'm not too familiar with the language.

I'm looking to create a simple script that will count the lines of a text file and then return the result as an integer. This is the code I have so far:

```
$lines = Get-Content -Path "C:\File"  | Measure-Object -Line
```

and it returns the following:

```
Lines Words Characters Property
----- ----- ---------- --------
8
```

However, I'm looking to return the 8 as a single integer so it can be stored as a variable. Is there an easy way to do this? I appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `.` operator like this:

```
(Get-Content -Path "C:\File" | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
```

What you had earlier was basically an object with 4 properties: "Lines", "Words", "Characters", and "Property". Using `.` is an easy way to access such properties.

Comment: Good answer. Seems like it should be more obvious.